# DataAdapter.Update returning syntax error C#

Tags: c#, dataset, oledb, dataadapter, oledbcommand

```
    void updateTaxPayer()
    {
        DataRow[] ssnRow = dbSet.Tables["TrackingSheet"].Select("SSN = '" + ssn + "'");
        ssnRow[0]["HAS SPOUSE"] = checkboxToString(chkSpouse.CheckState);
        ssnRow[0]["SPOUSE SSN"] = txtSpouseSSN.Text;
        ssnRow[0]["TNAME"] = txtName.Text;
        ssnRow[0]["ADDRESS"] = txtStreetAddress.Text;
        ssnRow[0]["CITY"] = txtCity.Text;
        ssnRow[0]["STATE"] = cbxState.SelectedIndex.ToString();
        ssnRow[0]["ZIP"] = txtZip.Text;
        ssnRow[0]["HAS NEW ADDRESS"] = checkboxToString(chkNewAddress.CheckState);
        ssnRow[0]["NEW ADDRESS"] = txtNewAddress.Text;
        ssnRow[0]["NEW CITY"] = txtNewCity.Text;
        ssnRow[0]["NEW STATE"] = cbxNewState.SelectedIndex.ToString();
        ssnRow[0]["NEW ZIP"] = txtNewZip.Text;
        ssnRow[0]["DATE FILED"] = txtDate.Text;
        ssnRow[0]["SSN"] = txtSSN.Text;
        dbAdapt.InsertCommand = cmdBuilder.GetInsertCommand(true);
        dbAdapt.UpdateCommand = cmdBuilder.GetUpdateCommand(true);
        dbAdapt.DeleteCommand = cmdBuilder.GetDeleteCommand(true);
        dbAdapt.Update(dbSet,"TrackingSheet");

    }
```

Above is the code that i have to update my database, but for some reason when i try to update I get a syntax error for the update command. I've searched around and i'm not sure what to do.

I've also tried dbAdapt.Update(dbSet, "TrackingSheet"); and that didn't work either.

The exact error is:

```
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException (0x80040E14): Syntax error in UPDATE statement.
   at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.UpdatedRowStatusErrors(RowUpdatedEventArgs rowUpdatedEvent, BatchCommandInfo[] batchCommands, Int32 commandCount)
   at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.UpdatedRowStatus(RowUpdatedEventArgs rowUpdatedEvent, BatchCommandInfo[] batchCommands, Int32 commandCount)
   at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Update(DataRow[] dataRows, DataTableMapping tableMapping)
   at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.UpdateFromDataTable(DataTable dataTable, DataTableMapping tableMapping)
   at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Update(DataSet dataSet, String srcTable)
   at trackingform.frmTrackingSheet.updateTaxPayer() in c:\Users\Anthony\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\trackingform\trackingform\frmTrackingSheet.cs:line 595
   at trackingform.frmTrackingSheet.btnSave_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\Users\Anthony\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\trackingform\trackingform\frmTrackingSheet.cs:line 506
```

Line 595: dbAdapt.Update(dbSet,"TrackingSheet");
Line 506: updateTaxPayer();

Other declarations:

```
dbAdapt = new OleDbDataAdapter();
cmdBuilder = new OleDbCommandBuilder(dbAdapt);
dbAdapt.SelectCommand = dbCmd;
dbSet = new DataSet("TrackingSheet");
dbAdapt.Fill(dbSet, "TrackingSheet");
```

Anyone have any ideas? Thanks

Comment: `The error is in the UPDATE statement` what does your `UPDATE Statement` look like..?

Comment: i thought that the cmdBuilder.getUpdateCommand(true); supplied me with an update statement.

i'm still new to db with c#

Comment: What is cmdBuilder? Post the code for the method GetUpdateCommand

Comment: http://pastebin.com/ynQBjf1c

Answer (score 0):

Can't say for sure, but I'd suspect that it has to do with the way you are naming your columns - using column names which contain spaces, and creating some ambiguity for the parser between part of a column name like "DATE" and reserved words or function names (like the "DATE" function). If you were to hand-code the statement, you'd enclose such column names in quotes so the SQL parser will understand them properly, but the command builder might not be doing that, and therefore producing invalid SQL.

As a general practice, I avoid using spaces in column names, and try to avoid using "reserved words"... because it's never certain what will or will not work.